# My random numbers are always zero?

Tags: java, class, variables, random

My program works perfectly, except for the fact that the random numbers I'm generating for the problems in my math game are always zero. I don't get it. I've tried using math.random, and I got the same problem. What is it doing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Problem {

    private int numberOfQuestions;
    private int answer;
    private int userAnswer; 
    private int score; 
    private int max;
    private int min;
    private static String question;
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int num1 = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    private int num2 = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;


    public Problem(int max, int min, int numberOfQuestions){

        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
        this.numberOfQuestions = numberOfQuestions;
    }

    public int multiplyNumbers()
    {
        answer = num1 * num2;
        return answer;
    }

    public String multiplyQuestion(){
        String sum = ("What is " + num1 +  " * " + num2 + "?");
        return sum;
    }

    public int addNumbers()
    {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        return answer;
    }

    public String addQuestion(){
        String sum = ("What is " + num1 +  " + " + num2 + "?");
        return sum;
    }

    public int subtractNumbers()
    {
        answer = num1 - num2;
        return answer;
    } 

    public String subtractQuestion(){
        String sum = ("What is " + num1 +  " - " + num2 + "?");
        return sum;
    }


    public int divideNumbers()
    {
        answer = num1 / num2;
        return answer;
    }

    public String divideQuestion(){
        String sum = ("What is " + num1 +  " / " + num2 + "?");
        return sum;
    }


    public String answer(int min, int max, int numberOfQuestions){
        int operator = (int)(Math.random()*4) + 1;
        if(operator == 1){
            question = addQuestion();
            answer = addNumbers();
        } else if(operator == 2) {
            question = subtractQuestion();
            answer = subtractNumbers();
        } else if(operator == 3) {
            question = divideQuestion();
            answer = divideNumbers();
        } else if(operator == 4) {
            question = multiplyQuestion();
            answer = multiplyNumbers();
        }

        System.out.println(question);
        userAnswer = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(answer);
        String result;
        int score = 0;
        if(userAnswer == answer){
            score = score + 1;
            result = "Correct. Score is currently: " + score + "/" + numberOfQuestions;
        } else {
            score = score - 1;
            result = "Incorrect. Score is currently: " + score + "/" + numberOfQuestions;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return "Math game~!" + answer(min, max, numberOfQuestions);
    }
}
```

Comment: `min` and `max` are being fed as values when they're not given values yet.

Comment: also to note that random isnt really random in a sense, it takes something to make random numbers so as an interrupt or what may be it so can be guessed if the pattern is found

Comment: Code runs from top to bottom.  Once you know this, the answer should be obvious.  The solution is to move the initialization to the constructor.

Answer (score 10):

Instance field initialization expressions are executed before the constructor body. So

```
private int num1 = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

is executed before

```
this.max = max;
this.min = min;
```

in the constructor.

At that point, the value of `max` and `min` is therefore the default `0`. Move the initialization statement of `num1` to the constructor body, after the assignments of `max` and `min`.